# Convert long to System.Int64 throws error?

Tags: c#

I got a strange error that got me buffeled:
I have a function ..uhm... something like this:

```
void someFunctionTakingALong( long ID)
{
  var table = new DataTable();
  table .Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RID", Type.GetType("System.Int64")));
  table.Rows.Add(ID);       //<-- throws err
}
```

throws this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in RID Column.  Expected type is Int64. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Data.Common.Int64Storage.Set(Int32 record, Object value)
   at System.Data.DataColumn.set_Item(Int32 record, Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

This happens in production, and I don't have logs to see what value of ID is actually passed to the function... but even so.. having the parameter a long should AT LEAST guarantee that ID is a long ... right? So why is this throwing? What values could ID have that are not convertible to a int64 ?

**EDIT:**

Here is the actual source : Trhowing column is **PropValueID**

```
public void AddRule(int PropID, long PropValueID, int type, string Data)
        {
            if (!m_HasRule)
            {
                m_Rules = new DataTable();
                m_Rules.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RID", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
                m_Rules.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PropID", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
                m_Rules.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PropValueID", Type.GetType("System.Int64")));
                //m_Rules.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PropValue", Type.GetType("System.String")));
                m_Rules.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
                m_Rules.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Data", Type.GetType("System.String")));
                m_HasRule = true;
            }
            ToStringSB = null;

            if (type<2)  // a "Is/Not specified property"
            {            
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Data)) //is specified (0,1)
                   m_Rules.Rows.Add(m_RID, PropID, 0, type, "");       //<<-- here we pass 0 (int32) instead of long.. could this be it? Stack says this is not the line throwing
                else  //is equal to/is not equal to(2,3) 
                    m_Rules.Rows.Add(m_RID, PropID, PropValueID,3-type, Data);                
            }else
                if ((type > 3) && (type < 6)) // a "like/not like" rule
                {
                    // "Like" or "not like" DATA .. no value ID is provided
                    m_Rules.Rows.Add(m_RID, PropID, PropValueID, type, Data); //<<-- Stack says it throws here 

                }
                else // a greater/lesser rule
                {
                    m_Rules.Rows.Add(m_RID, PropID, PropValueID, type, Data);
                }

        }
```

There is a suspect line where we pass on literal 0 (an int) but that's not the line number where the stack says it throws.

Comment: I don't always test my code; but when I do, I do it in production.

Comment: note: instead of using `Type.GetType("System.Int64")`, use `typeof(long)` or `typeof(System.Int64)`.

Comment: `Input string was not in a correct format` tells me that something is expecting a string, but it should actually expect and `object` or a `System.Int64` lol @ testing in prod

Comment: Are you sure that the value at `DataColumn["RID"]` is actually a numeric string?

Comment: For international users who don't get @Brandon 's reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Bc0WjTT0Ps

Comment: Can you show us the actual code? What version of the .Net Framework are you using?

Answer (score 7):

Unable to reproduce - this works fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long x = 10;
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RID", Type.GetType("System.Int64")));
        table.Rows.Add(x);
    }
}
```

Note that you can get rid of the call to `Type.GetType()` by using `typeof(long)`.

It looks like for some reason it's converting the value to a string and back, which is *really* strange... are you sure it's from just that code?

If you can come up with a short but complete example like mine but which fails, that would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are passing a `long` to the `DataRowCollection.Add` method?

The code snippet you posted doesn't help much, can you post the actual code?

The `System.Data` namespace code pre-dates generics, so there's a lot of boxing and unboxing going on, and I think there's no way around it. From the stack trace we can see that the code is trying to set the value of a `DataRow` column from an `Object` value, and that this results in a `String` parse to `Int64`.  This leads me to believe that the call to `table.Rows.Add` is not receiving a `long` value for the `RID` column. Unless the boxing messed up the `long` value and ended up as an empty `String`, which although is not impossible is extremely improbable. By that I mean, I didn't code the .Net Framework, I don't know what does it do internally, in general we trust that Microsoft did a good job, but in all code there's the possibility of error. So either the bug is in your code or in Microsoft's code. The odds are against you.

Comment: hmm... what would be a case of a long converted to an invalid/empty string.. are there special cases of long ? ie . #INF #NAN ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code in production? I don't see a difference in the "like/not like rule" and "greater/lesser rule" code that adds the row to the collection.  From the comments it says `no value ID is provided`. Could it be that the actual code is: `m_Rules.Rows.Add(m_RID, PropID, "", type, Data);` or something like that?